# RMSE normalization. Number of bins

Tags: normalization, goodness-of-fit, rms

I am using RMSE (Root mean squared error) as a measure of goodness of fit.
I am fitting a formula to binned data. The number of bins is not fixed: if there are less than 5 data values in a certain bin, I don't use this bin.

Is there a way to normalize the RMSE? For example, dividing by the number of bins. If not, in certain cases with just very few bins I get a low RMSE because only the differences with respect to those few bins are added.

Comment: How are you calculating MSE?

Comment: the square root of the sum of the squared differences between the data values (bins) and the values obtained from the fit formula

Comment: Well, that is how I calculate RMSE

Comment: At what point do you take the mean? You don’t appear to be dividing by the number of observations.

Comment: Oh! I see your point! That would solve my problem, of course. And is actually in the definition of rMse

Comment: Yes! I don't think the bins end up mattering, just how many values are in your regression.

Comment: Your rule for not using certain bins appears to be a misinterpretation of a rule of thumb in the chi-squared test that suggests the chi-squared distribution might not be a good approximation to its statistic when the *expected* count of the bin is less than $5.$  Ignoring those situations is inadmissible, because it's demonstrably inferior to any analysis that incorporates the information in those bins somehow.